# Is the chord progression of this short piece C-G7-C?

Tags: theory, harmony, chord-progressions, analysis

[image: 6 measure piece]

Is the chord progression of this short piece C-G7-C? I'm new to music theory and want to confirm my understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

The first two measures outline a C major chord. Since there are no other notes involved, C major is the interpretation.

The next two measures outline a G7 chord, even though the B is excluded. Since the previous two measures were G major, G7 is the principle option here.

The final measure is again C major for the same reason as the first two measures, reinforced by the fact that C major would be the expected destination of the G7 chord.

Comment: Yes, although to be precise, the G7 chord appears in second inversion.  Just mentioning so the OP realizes that their basic analysis is correct, but there is a further nuance to be aware of!

Comment: @nuggethead That's an interesting thought. Since the B isn't present, it's not obvious which inversion is being used. Since the C is always the lowest pitch in the C major chord, the presumptive inversion for the G7 would be first. For second inversion, the B would have to be above the G, and the leading tone resolving downward in an outer voice would be uncharacteristic (if not forbidden).

Comment: fair enough!   Perhaps a better way to respond is for me to say, "yes it is C-G7-C, but be aware of the fact the the G7 is missing a pitch and not in root position. "

Comment: Of course there's nothing wrong with omitting the B nor avoiding root position

Comment: @nuggethead I think these comments make a nice supplement to the answer. Since OP is clearly a very beginning beginner, I'd prefer to leave discussion of inversions to another question.

Comment: @Aaron Could you elaborate on "Since the C is always the lowest pitch in the C major chord, the presumptive inversion for the G7 would be first."?

Comment: @xrosaber When analyzing a series of chords, it is typical to treat each note as though it were part of an independent melody ("voice"). In the case of your piece, the G is the top note in each chord; the middle voice is E-F-E; and the lowest voice is C-D-C. Were a B to be added to your G7 chord, it would either be the lowest note (thus 1st inversion) or the highest (thus 2nd inversion).

Comment: @xrosaber  Allowing there were no other changes, and presuming characteristic voice-leading, the B could not be the topmost note, because when in an outer voice (lowest or highest), it must resolve to C. The theoretical B would have to be in the lowest voice.

Comment: It could also  be C to Dm with an upper neighbor on the downbeat…

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy Isn't a neighbor tone stepped into?

Comment: @xrosaber There can be "incomplete neighbor" tones; however, given what you've written, it's unlikely someone would hear those two measures as D minor.

Answer (score 0):

It is basically I - V7- I, C - G7 - C. As  bourn out by the triad notes of C major (C E G) and G7 (G D F). It's rather unusual, though, to omit the 3rd of a chord - this tells whether it's major or minor. That missing B♮ would make the chord definitely G7, although it *could* have been B♭, making Gm7, often heralding an F chord. So it's a little ambiguous as it stands.

From a beginner point of view, though, C - G7 - C will suffice. Not sure whether *inversions* are relevant here, as the notes are not in chord form, only sort of arpeggiated. The V7 chord usually contains notes 4 and 7, which make the tritone that sounds like it needs resolving. Interestingly, those are the two notes left out of the scale , when making the 'safe' pentatonic.

Comment: Not really relevant to OP's question,  but how did you get the flat and natural symbols to appear in-line with text?

Comment: @nuggethead - &natural;  &sharp; &flat;.

Comment: @Tim What do you mean by "Gm7, often heralding an F chord."?

Comment: @xrosaber - the chord Gm7 contains G Bb and D - all components of C9, the dominant of  chord F. It's often used (by me at least) instead of C7, as a precursor of F.

Answer (score -4):

C (3rd inversion) and a G5add7.

Comment: Third inversion? For a triad?

Comment: CEG is 1st inversion, EGC is second inversion, GCE is third inversion. Since the melody start with a G C E I'd say the underlying chord was C third inversion.

Comment: And the transition from C third inversion to the G5(add 7) is very easy.  You only have to move your fingers from G C E to G D F.

Comment: CEG is root position; EGC is first inversion; and GCE is third inversion. The chord position is named according to the lowest pitch, not the order of pitches, so this is root position, as C is the lowest pitch.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. 2nd inversion.   So, replace 3rd with 2nd. I'm still fine with my answer.  I agree the underlying chord is C. I'm just saying you should use the 2nd inversion rather than the root position.  I'm playing it on the piano. The chord progression requires moving 2 fingers a whole step in either hand.